# how to refer name of several combo boxs by their name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am working on a workbook with many combo boxes. 
The code below is a code that takes a list of combo boxes and passes them to the cell range. 
Is there a way to reference a combo box in the VBA code with the name of the combo box? 
I would like to refer to the name of the combo box by including variable instead of directly. For example, "cboAct" & i.List = actList

The codes are as follows;

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim actList() As String
Dim i As Integer


Set sheet = Worksheets("DB")


i = sheet.Range("B3").End(xlDown).row


ReDim actList(1 To i - 2)

k = 1

For Each c In sheet.Range("B3:B" & i)

    If k = 1 Then

        actList(k) = c.value

        k = k + 1

    ElseIf c.value <> actList(k - 1) Then

        actList(k) = c.value

        k = k + 1

    End If

Next c


cboAct1.List = actList
cboAct2.List = actList
cboAct3.List = actList
cboAct4.List = actList
cboAct5.List = actList
cboAct6.List = actList
cboAct7.List = actList
cboAct8.List = actList
cboAct9.List = actList
cboAct10.List = actList
cboAct11.List = actList
cboAct12.List = actList
cboAct13.List = actList
cboAct14.List = actList
cboAct15.List = actList

End Sub
```

My question is, can I write the code by referring to the name of combo box below with variable? I want to write code by referring to the name of a specific combo box rather than code like "For Each combo in sheets.combo box".

cboAct1.List = actList

cboAct2.List = actList

cboAct3.List = actList

......................

cboAct15.List = actList

Comment: What happens when you try that?  ...have you tried?

Comment: The above code works normally. I would like to refer to the name of the combo box by including variable instead of directly. For example, "cboAct" & i.list = actList

Comment: I solve the problem!     For i = 1 To 15

       Me.Controls("cboAct" & i).List = actList

       Next i

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem!

```
For i = 1 To 15 Me.Controls("cboAct" & i).List = actList Next i
```